# Getting user input with function

Tags: python, function, input

Here is my code:

```
def bitcoin_to_usd(btc):
    amount = btc * 527
    print(amount)

btc = input("Input your Bitcoins amount: ")

bitcoin_to_usd(btc)
```

I want to get Bitcoin number from user then I want to calculate how much USD is it.

That code gives me repetition of the input. Such as if you input `2` it returns `222222222222222222222222....` doesn't calculate it.

My Python version is 3.4.1 and I am using PyCharm.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine except that you need to convert the result of input, which returns a string, to a number. Let's try `float` for a floating-point datatype:

```
def bitcoin_to_usd(btc):
    amount = btc * 527
    print(amount)

btc = float( input("Input your Bitcoins amount: ") )

bitcoin_to_usd(btc)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3.x, `input` returns a *string*<sup>1</sup>, not a number.  If you want a number, you should convert the input string to a float or int.

```
btc = float(input("Input your Bitcoins amount: "))
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>This explains the results as well, multiplying a string by an integer causes the string to be concatenated with itself that number of times.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
btc = input("Input your Bitcoins amount: ")

def bitcoin_to_usd(btc):
    amount = btc * 527
    print(amount)


bitcoin_to_usd(btc)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this where the function has no parameter :

```
    def sum():
        return x+y
    x = int(input("Val of x"))
    y = int(input("Val of y"))
    print(sum())
```

or you can also try this one where the function has the parameter:

```
def sum(x,y):
       return x+y
x = int(input("Val of x"))
y = int(input("Val of y"))
print(sum(x,y))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below line inside your  defined function:

```
amount = float(btc) * 527
```